# Stable version of PhpSpreadsheet (PhpExcel)

Tags: php, git, phpexcel, phpoffice, phpspreadsheet

I tried to use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). In Issues section I found that the [master branch is now broken](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/155).

I tried to use the develop branch, but I can't find a fully functional and ready to copy\paste version. There are no Autoloader.php and etc. like in the stable branch. I just want to use this library.

In master branch I found

[image]

After I can use this library like this

```
require_once 'Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Autoloader::register();
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
```

What can I do to use develop branch without any difficult?

Comment: This library is current still in development, and pre-release; so the best thing for you to do if you want to use it is help the developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use [PHP composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to define the version of '[phpoffice/phpspreadsheet](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet#dev-develop)' you want to run.

In my case, i declare this dependency in my project

```
{
  "require": {
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "dev-develop"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A tagged beta version has just been released.

```
{
   "require": {
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "1.0.0-beta"
  }
}
```